# Serialize to AMF exactly like NetConnection does

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serialization, amf

I want to serialize an object to AMF, and I want the result to be exactly the same as if it is serialized by NetConnection.call(). So, I use ByteArray.writeObject(), and the output bytes are usually the same as bytes sent by NetConnection.call(), but sometimes couple of bytes are different.

I found this in AMF3 spec: "Note that ByteArray.writeObject uses one version of AMF to encode the entire object. Unlike NetConnection, ByteArray does not start out in AMF 0 and switch to AMF 3 (with the objectEncoding property set to AMF 3)." It explains that differences.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Little tip : check AMFPHP, how PHP encoder works , because it use NetConnection => php encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that NetConnection.call works and how to construct valid requests and responses is documented in detail in the [AMF0 specs](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf0_spec_121207.pdf) in section 4. NetConnection.call has some additional functionality, like headers, the RPC method name, and whether or not the request was successful or ran into an error. This is why you can't just use writeObject to create a valid request.

The bit about switching from AMF0 to AMF3 is due to the fact that not every AS3 object can be written without a loss of data in AMF0, but original Flash Players all assumed that the body would be in AMF0. What happens is that during encoding, if you've specified that you want to use AMF3 for encoding, it writes out an AMF0-to-AMF3 marker (`0x11`) before calling writeObject in AMF3 mode.